# Starting web server apache2 failed

Tags: apache, nginx

I have a Virtual Server. Till yesterday everything works fine on it.
Today my Hostcompany restarted my server to config something on I/O.

When I trying to get to my address I get

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further    configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

I tried to `sudo service apache2 start` and get these Error Message:

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                                                                     

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
* 
* The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Does someone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Is nginx running on the same host? It is listening port 80 instead of Apache.

Comment: how can I verify if nginx is running? I never installed it :/

Comment: try `/usr/bin/nginx -s stop` or `locate nginx` to find if it is installed. It might be just a front-end on the hoster's side. But obviously something is already listening port 80

Comment: locate nginx
/etc/nginx
/etc/default/nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
/etc/nginx/conf.d
/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params etc...  there is a lot ... / how can I remove it?

Comment: Make `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop`

Comment: I have done this. And when I run $ sudo apt-get remove nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt-get purge nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.

Comment: Then make is was answered below, but with root rights - `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` to see what is listening port 80. May be it is another instance of Apache.

Comment: 1133/nginx: worker is listening on port 80

Comment: So, you have nginx running. May be installed differently or not as a package. You can kill its process, but it will start again after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

**Stop Nginx** `service nginx stop`

**Restart Apache** `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

You have another webserver that's running on the host (probably as part of the startup during the restart) You need to shut that off first.

You can run `netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and that'll tell you what that process is

Comment: netstat -tulpn | grep :80
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     --

Comment: Arguments could be different for your OS, and I'm not sure what that is. If you read upon netstat documentations that'll tell you how to run it. Also it seems like your host has given you a limited access to netstat as the error message explains you have to be root

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this, Nginx (another web server engine) it's using your port 80 so apache it's unable to start, a fast fix it turn of nginx and then restart apache.

You can do it with **service nginx stop** and **service apache2 restart** if you are using Ubuntu or Debian based release, if you are using an RHEL distro then use **service nginx stop** and **service httpd restart**

Comment: next error :/$ sudo service nginx stop
$ service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2
* The apache2 configtest failed. [fail]

Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf:
FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi: 
access for server (uid 1000, gid 1000) 
failed: write not allowed
Action 'configtest' failed.

less /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
  #FastCgiWrapper /usr/lib/apache2/suexec
  FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

first: `sudo update-rc.d -f nginx remove`
than:  `sudo rm /etc/init.d/nginx`

after restarting VM almost everything works fine. Some strange thing is almost there.

When I goto `www.myfoobarwebpage.com` now apache is working and it's all ok!
When I goto `myfoobarwebpage.com` (without www.) I get "Welcome to nginx! ..."

Comment: Check for `ServerAlias www.myfoobarwebpage.com` in your `site-available` and `site-enabled` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. My Apache config has 2 extra lines by mistake.

`"Include conf/extra/httpd-8080.conf"`

`"Include conf/extra/httpd-8080.conf"`

Therefore, it was saying address already in use because it already loaded the Virtual host once and was trying again.

Solution was to delete this extra line and have only one include.